# Does Reversed WINE exist?

Tags: windows, wine, windows-7

I have a friend who wants to run a Linux application on their Windows 7 installation. I've checked and there is no Windows version.

What I think I need is a WINE that works the other way round, i.e. converting Linux calls to Windows.

Does this exist? I don't want to install Linux on their machine or run Virtualbox.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Depending on the app it may or may not run with the Dash for Windows. But this question is a Windows question. You should get support at https://superuser.com/

Comment: @CelticWarrior if you mean WSL, I'm pretty certain that's Windows 10-only

Comment: Correction: i meant Bash, obviously. And yes, only for Windows 10. And I must add I don't know of any Linux emulator for Windows, only some utilities to access EXTx partitions.

Comment: Maybe [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) can help.

Comment: [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) additionally suggest [cygwin](https://superuser.com/a/452047/42972). Check if the application is already packaged for cygwin. Else you will need to grab the source and compile it yourself.

Comment: I use Bash on Windows 10 often.  Works very well, even GUI apps work by installing something like Xming, which also allow GUI apps to open over SSH from Windows.  If this is something he really needs, he should consider upgrading to W10.

Answer (score 2):

[5 Ways to Run Linux Software on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/170870/5-ways-to-run-linux-software-on-windows/):

- Virtual machine
- Cygwin
- Install Ubuntu via Wubi
- Ported and Compiled Programs ...

Comment: Wubi installs haven't been supported for quite some time. And... I count 4 in your list, not 5...

Comment: That's why there are "...". Read the article :)